# Detecting paragraph breaks with Regex - edge case problem

Tags: python, regex

I have a long text string with poorly formated new lines. I want to remove all of the newlines chars except for when the newline char follows a `.`, `?`, `!`, `:` char (as that would indicate the end of a sentence). I also don't want to remove the newline if it's immediately followed by a number or another newline - that would indicate a chapter ending. I'm using python `re` for regex.

Here is my regex so far `(?<!\?|\.|:|\n)\n(?![\d]|\n)`

Regex example with 7 unit test cases: https://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/1118

My test is failing in the following example:

```
First paragraph.  <-- note a trailing space(s) after the period
Second paragraph
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it necessary to fix it all with one regular expression in one step?

Comment: This regex removes all newlines in the document except for the few important ones. Once they are gone, I have no way to go back and reinsert them. So it has to be done in one step.

Comment: You could try ((?<![\?\.:!\n])|(?<![\?\.:!\n][ \t]))\n(?![\d]|\n)
Negative look behinds do not let one or more spaces be selected, but this does fit one tab or space. You also didn't include an exclamation point for the set of characters to check for in your regex. I would have used an answer, but I don't like the answer and still have to work/check on it.

Comment: You do not have `First paragraph.` in the text you supplied. Also, according to the rules you outlined the pattern is just `\n(?![.?!:\d\n\r])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [regex PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and in the lookbehind match optional whitespace characters without a newline using `[^\S\r\n]*` after matching  one of `?` `.` `:` or a newline.

You can shorten using an alternation `|` to using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) listing all the characters.

```
(?<![?.:\n\r][^\S\r\n]*)\r?\n(?![\d\r\n])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/738rvh/1) (Selected the JavaScript engine for the example)

Comment: this works with the regex package! In general will be using regex over re from now on

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the text above, we may conclude that the actual bad formating is resulting from the presence of a lot of spaces.
Therefor it colud be treated by subistituting each block of spaced between words/letters `([a-zA-Z])\s+([a-zA-Z])`with one space `\1 \2` like

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\s+([a-zA-Z])','\1 \2',Text)
```

According to the following link: https://regex101.com/r/feRwne/1

finally, copy and paste the result in a word document, to ensure is acceptable or not.